# Is there a name for this equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I want to know if there's a name for the following equation and how correctly to write this formula? $$z = \frac{x - y}{\min(x, y)}$$

Comment: I might call it a "symmetric relative difference", but this is unofficial. And there is a variant with the max.

Comment: Use `$z=\frac{x-y}{\min(x,y)}$` to write it (you can replace by `\dfrac` for a normal size fraction). Here is the link to the mathjax faq https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/399263

Answer (score 1):

That equation has no particular name. You can invent one if you need one. (Be careful not to divide by $0$.)